# Force.com migration tool metadata not retrieved

Tags: migration-tool

I am using ant target from the migration tool to retrieve all the medata from one of my sandboxes. In the list of metadata retrieved I don't have dashboard, email, reports, all is empty. But when I use the eclipse plugin and sync with server all this metadata appears. Can someone explain me why I have this difference ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your `package.xml` look like?

Comment: My package.xml is huge but there is not entries for dashboards. The problem is when I call sf:listMetadata, it doesn't return any dashboards when I specify metadataType=Dashboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these metadata types, you can't simply retrieve all of them with the `*` notation. To retrieve them, you need to request them specifically by name and include the folder that they are in.

When the eclipse plugin generates the package.xml file, it is doing that work for you behind the scenes.

A good reference to consult when working with metadata is the [Metadata API Developers' Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_dashboard.htm)

---

When calling `describeMetadata()`, you will notice that certain metadataObjects are being returned with the value of `inFolder` set to true. These objects have another object that is not returned from the `describeMetadata()` call that are named with the word "Folder" at the end (DashboardFolder, ReportFolder, etc.). To get the metadata for these types, you should use the +Folder object names in the `listMetadata()` call.

Comment: I don't use the * notation. Actually my job work like this :
1. Call sf:describeMetadata - to get all kind of metadata
2. Call for each metaData sf:listMetadata - but here for dashboards I have nothing and that's my problem
3. Create a package.xml with each elements coming from the listMedata job
So to be more specific my question is : Why sf:listMetadata doesn't return any dashboards when I specify metadataType=Dashboard ?

Comment: @SébastienVanCutsem So, in the case of Dashboards, you would want to specify `metadataType=DashboardFolder` when running sf:listMetadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have still one question. I have a metadata descitpion which says : 
`XMLName: EmailTemplate
DirName: email
Suffix: email
HasMetaFile: true
InFolder: true
ChildObjects:`
So I tried sf:listMetadata with metadataType=EmailTemplateFolder but that says INVALID_TYPE: Unknown type:EmailTemplateFolder. So it's not a general rule to say each time I have InFolder=true I can add Folder to the XMLName ??

Comment: @SébastienVanCutsem Interesting. It looks like EmailTemplate is an exception to the rule.